# Input and Store names in array - Java

Tags: java

I have been trying out this questions however I still cannot find the solution to it. Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Question - Declare and create an array to store the names of four players.  Call the array pNames.

Ask the user to input the names of the four players and store their names in the pNames array.

```
  Enter Name of Player 1 > Johnny
  Enter Name of Player 2 > Jackie
  Enter Name of Player 3 > Jessie
  Enter Name of Player 4 > Jeremy
```

Output a hello message to greet each player.

```
Hello Johnny
Hello Jackie
Hello Jessie
Hello Jeremy
```

Answer:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Q2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] pNames = new String[4];

    for(int i = 1; i <= pNames.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + i + " > ");

        pNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[0]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[1]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[2]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[3]);
}
```

}

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Arrays are 0 index based.

In the loop you are using a 1 index base.

Change

```
for(int i = 1; i <= pNames.length; i++) {

    System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + i + " > ");

    pNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

to

```
for(int i = 1; i <= pNames.length; i++) {

    System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + i + " > ");

    // The index of pNames must start from 0!
    pNames[i-1] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

---

A solution closer to the mode of reasoning of programmers is to use a loop starting from 0 and change the System.out as follow:

```
// Loop start from 0 and goes to 4 excluded
for (int i = 0; i < pNames.length; i++) {

    // To print Enter name of Player 1 change i to (i + 1)
    System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + (i + 1) + " > ");

    pNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: its better to start at zero and change (i <= pNames.length) to (i < pNames.length)

Comment: @nabeel No... the condition is correct because the for starts from 1 and not from 0.

Comment: I assume he wants it to be Player 1, and not Player 0 @nabeel

Comment: both works fine, but its better to learn and understand that array start at zero index :-)

Comment: @nabeel If the loop starts from 0 you need to change the System.out adding 1 to print the correct index from 1 to 4 and not from 0 to 3

Comment: yes, personally i would much this approach (updating the display with +1 instead of adapting all code for easier display)

Comment: you just copied my code

Comment: @AkshayBheda see the times.... I updated my answer just 10 seconds after  your answer. I was writing at the time, not looking at your code. In any case +1 from me

Comment: @DavideLorenzoMARINO +1 from me too. Sorry

Answer (score 2):

Instead of starting index from 1, you need to start the array index to 0 and while displaying "Enter Name of player", just display incremented value of i by 1

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Q2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    String [] pNames = new String[4];

    for(int i = 0; i < pNames.length; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + (i+1) + " > ");

        pNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[0]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[1]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[2]);
    System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[3]);
}
```

Comment: This code is not correct because it ask for "Enter name of player 0 >" that is not what it was required

Comment: To add, you should put in *some* sort of comment to explain what's different with your code to the OPs

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

Start the for from 0 and use `sc.Next();` instead of `sc.nextLine();`:

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Q2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

String [] pNames = new String[4];

for(int i = 0; i < pNames.length; i++) {

    int a = i+1;
    System.out.print("Enter name of Player" + " " + a + " > ");

    pNames[i] = sc.next();
}

System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[0]);
System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[1]);
System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[2]);
System.out.println("Hello" + " " + pNames[3]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this line:

```
pNames[i] = sc.nextLine();
```

to this:

```
pNames[i-1] = sc.nextLine();
```

Since you are accessing 1 to 4, your array is actually on the range 0-3, so you need to subtract one.